Dunnett's test for comparisons with Control - how to conduct ANOVA for 2 factors, as well as adjusting for different experimental designs?
From what I understand, before we conduct Dunnett's test for comparisons of treatments to a Control, we have to do ANOVA. However, for a 2-factor experiment, there seem to be a lot of problems to me.
Let's say I have this experiment:



BA (mg/L)
NAA (mg/L)
number of shoots




0.5
0.1
2.0


0.5
0.1
2.1


0.5
0.1
2.1


0.5
0.2
1.7


0.5
0.2
1.6


0.5
0.2
1.5


1.0
0.1
3.6


1.0
0.1
3.4


1.0
0.1
3.2


1.0
0.2
2.3


1.0
0.2
2.3


1.0
0.2
2.1


Control (TDZ 1 mg/L)

3.0


Control (TDZ 1 mg/L)

3.3


Control (TDZ 1 mg/L)

3.0



To do Dunnett's test, I have to perform ANOVA (one-way) beforehand on all 5 treatments (including Control), which wouldn't make sense in my opinion. Not only would it compress the 2 factors (BA and NAA) together and I would lose any information about their interaction, the TDZ Control technically aren't related at all to the 2 factors (BA and NAA), so would doing ANOVA with them together even make sense? That's not to mention when doing ANOVA, we have to do adjustment for the experimental design, for example, if the 2 factors above were arranged in a split plot design instead of a CRD design. If we add Control into that mess, how would that adjustment turn out?

You do not need to do ANOVA before you do Dunnet's test. See Wikipedia.
